# Conflicting HTAccess files - rewrites and 301s not working for wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two sites hosted on one server. An old one in a subdirectory and a new one in the root folder.

blog.domain.com in /var/www/     -     The Current Site

blog.domain.com/blog in /var/www/blog/     -     The Old Site

blog.domain.com/blog is the legacy site that we need to redirect to the new one for various reasons.

I have added a load of 301s to htaccess in the /var/wwww/blog/ folder:

```
Redirect 301 / http://blog.domain.com
Redirect 301 /subfolder/ http://blog.domain.com
```

However when I visit htttp://blog.domain.com/blog I get redirected to http://blog.domain.comblog instead of: http://blog.domain.com

Here are the existing HTAccess files:
/var/www/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^78\.41\.157\.192$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

/var/www/blog/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Redirect 301 / http://blog.domain.com
Redirect 301 /subfolder/ http://blog.domain.com
```

I did not write the htaccess files, any insight into any errors or why adding 301s wouldnt work would be great. I presume its due to a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is you're missing a `/` at the end of your redirect destination. Apache's `Redirect` simply matches the target URI then appends anything after it to the destination. So:

```
Redirect 301 / http://blog.domain.com/
Redirect 301 /subfolder/ http://blog.domain.com/
```

However, since you have wordpress routing rules, you're not going to want to use `Redirect` at all. `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite, which means when a requested URL matches both modules, they both get applied. So you'll get some weird unanticipated redirection. Try using mod_rewrite only, and add these rules **before** your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://blog.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^subfolder/?$ http://blog.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks!

3000 redirect edits later it works perfectly. Last question, how do I avoid the 404 page of the old site?

Comment: @AirCombat you can try looking into `FallbackResource` directive. If something is not found, it just gets routed to that.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up editing RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] to RewriteRule . /index.php [L] which redirects to the new sites 404 instead of ideally the home page but that's good enough.